# `Unknown` file download after reload in Safari 8.0 on OS X Yosemite

Tags: safari, macos

Since upgrading to OS X Yosemite I've experienced that sometimes when reloading a web page (CMD+R) Safari doesn't reload the page but downloads a file named `Unknown`.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's such a pain!

Comment: @Rog Unfortunately no

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Not always, but on occasions pressing Cmd+R to reload, just results in a download of an empty file named 'Unknown'. It's somewhat annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is not an empty file but malware from 'carpet bombing'. Do not attempt to open the file but get info on the file and you should see it is from known malicious sites. I am scanning my system right now using ClamXav and nothing is coming up bad so I suspect it will go away if you just keep trashing the files until the hacker gives up. If anyone knows more than this please contribute.

Comment: I'm getting them too. They are empty files (zero byte TextEdit documents).

Answer (score 0):

A file with 0 Bytes is just annoying but harmless. Opening a 0-byte-file is harmless, too, because it contains nothing.